# Formatting date string with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have date string that looks like this:

```
'Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:05:21 EST -05:00'
```

I was trying to do this with moment.js:

```
moment(new Date('Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:05:21 EST -05:00'), "MM-DD-YYYY").toString();
```

but this returns: Invalid Date...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
moment(new Date('Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:05:21 EST -05:00')).format('MM-DD-YYYY'); // 01-18-2016
```

Comment: Hmm, so how can I transform this: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:05:21 EST -05:00 to this "2014-02-27T10:00:00" with javascript?

Comment: @kyrylkov you can pass that string to `new Date()`

Comment: If using a parser, use it, don't rely on the built–in parser (which is why there's a need for libraries to do the job).

Answer (score 1):

Try this pure JS version:

```js
var d = new Date('Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:05:21 EST -05:00');

document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = d.toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g,"-")
```

```html
<div id="body"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try in this way.

```js
var strDate = 'Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:05:21 EST -05:00';
strDate = new Date(strDate);
var strNewDate = new moment(strDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

console.log(strNewDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You need to convert string to Date object.Then create moment object

Answer (score 1):

When you use momentjs, don't use Date. You have to provide a custom format to moment:

```js
var input = 'Mon, 18 Jan 2016 05:05:21 EST -05:00';

// use custom format here
var date = moment(input, 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');

// format() without argument return an ISO date
$('#pre').append(date.format());
$('#pre').append('\n');
$('#pre').append(date.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<pre id='pre'></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no readily available way to parse `EST -05:00`. Since EST -05 equals UTC `+00:00`, you would have to do instead:

```
dateString = 'Mon, 18 Jan 2016 01:05:21 +00:00';
dateFormat = 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ';
moment(dateString, dateFormat).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
```